# glTexSubImage2D is slower with Pixel Buffer Objects

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am using PBO in opengl es3 on android but after using them, performance of data unpacking has degraded. Please help me in finding fault in the code.
Background: My app consist of a module which generates images at a very fast rate. These images are uploaded to textures which are finally drawn on TextureView. Bottleneck in my app is time taken in uploading images to textures.
I decided to try PBOs to improve this perf. Below is my code:

One time initialization

```
  CheckGLErr( glGenTextures( 1, &texName ) );

  if( usePBO )
  {
     CheckGLErr( glGenBuffers( 1, &pboId ) );
     CheckGLErr( glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pboId ) );
     CheckGLErr( glBufferData( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, textureSize, 0, GL_STREAM_DRAW ) );
     CheckGLErr( glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0 ) );
  }

  glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName );
  glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );
  glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );
```

RenderLoop:

```
 CheckGLErr(glClearColor(0, 1.0f, 0, 1));
 CheckGLErr(glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT));

  glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName );

  if( usePBO )
  {
     CheckGLErr(glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pboId ));
     void* pBuff = ::glMapBufferRange( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0, textureSize , GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT );
     memcpy( pBuff, buffer.get(), textureSize );
     CheckGLErr(glUnmapBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER ));
  }

  //std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 100 ) );

  glTexSubImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, usePBO ? 0 : buffer.get() );

  // Setup texture properties.
  CheckGLErr(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST));
  CheckGLErr(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST));
  CheckGLErr(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
  CheckGLErr(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));

  CheckGLErr( glUseProgram( programObject ) );


  // Enable position vertex attribute. Its size is 3 floats corresponding for co-ordinates in three directions.
  CheckGLErr(glEnableVertexAttribArray(0));
  CheckGLErr(glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * sizeof(float)/*vertexStride*/, (const GLvoid *)0));

  // Enable UV vertex attribute which starts after position. Hence offset = 3 floats.
  CheckGLErr(glEnableVertexAttribArray(1));
  CheckGLErr(glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * sizeof(float)/*vertexStride*/, (const GLvoid *)(3*sizeof(float))/*offset worth position*/));

  // Setup ViewPort
  CheckGLErr(glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight));

  if(usePBO )
     CheckGLErr( glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0 ) );

  CheckGLErr(glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, _countof(indices), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid *)0x00000000));
  eglSwapBuffers(eglDisplay, eglWindowSurface);
```

Measurements Done:
On Nexus 7 (4.4.4) Adreno GPU
Screen Size = 1624 * 1200 pixels
    Without PBO : 17 ms
    With PBO : 18 ms (~ 5ms for buffer population and rest in glTexSubImage2D call)

On Nexus 6 (5.0)
Screen Size = 2042 * 1440 pixels
Without PBO : 6 ms
With PBO : 20 ms

My assumption was on using PBOs glTexSubImage2D should return instanteously(or at least in < 5ms) because image data is already in VRAM but in fact it is taking much longer specially on Nexus 6.
As an experiment I put std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 100 ) ); between glUnmapBuffer and glTexSubImage2d to see whether it makes any difference in time taken by only glTexSubImage2D but it remained same.

Comment: I think it is depends of hardware and driver. You may have different result on different phones (as you see). Also with PBO you use glBindBuffer and make some operation to copy buffer to texture. I think it may be a little slowly, but I repeat, it depends on hardware. As another variant you can try to generate images on GPU.

Comment: Also you can try to transfer data in native texture format. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17587/how-detect-which-opengl-texture-formats-are-natively-supported

Comment: @Unick, Thanks for your reply. Its not feasible for me to generate images on GPU. I can understand that exact time taken for pixel transfer will depend on how driver is implemented but I do not understand why using PBO has not resulted in improvement in pixel transfers. PBOs are after all introduced to make pixel packing & unpacking faster. That's why I think probably there is something wrong in my code & may be I have not used them properly.

Comment: @Unick, OpenGL ES3 supports only GL_RGB or GL_RGBA as texture internal format & pixel data format, see [link](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml). So I think I can't experiment on texture format.

Comment: @BhanuSingh, did you ever figure out what was causing this or find a solution? I'm running into a similar problem. Thanks.